# Child Widget value is not changing in Flutter Consumer widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Hello please i am trying to pass a Video source from a provider class i create. It work every other places i use it like get the video thumbs etc. But am tryting to pass the video source to a my video widget. when i select the video it does not update but if i navigate away and come back the source will be updated. I want it to update as i change the video source.

Here are my codes i am currently batting with:

channel_provider.dart:

```
   Map selectedChannel = {};

// Select channel
  void selectChannel(Map channel) {
    selectedChannel = channel;
    saveRecentChannel(channel);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Home Screen that list all channels and also contain video player

```
Consumer<ChannelProvider>(
          builder: (context, channelProvider, _) =>
              channelProvider.selectedChannel.isNotEmpty
                  ? SizedBox(
                      height: context.height() / 3.8,
                      child: VideoPlayerBox(channelProvider.getSelectedVideo),
                    )
                  : Shimmer.fromColors(
                      baseColor: Colors.grey,
                      highlightColor: Colors.white,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: context.height() / 3.8,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Loading...',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
        ),
```

Video player box widget:

```
class _VideoPlayerBoxState extends State<VideoPlayerBox> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  ChewieController? _chewieController;
  var _videoSource;

  @override
  void initState() {
  _videoSource = widget.channel;
    iniVideo();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> iniVideo() async {
    log(_videoSource['link']);
    log('hi');
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(_videoSource['link']);
    await _controller.initialize();

    setState(() {
      _chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _controller,
        autoPlay: true,
        isLive: true,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _chewieController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _chewieController != null
        ? SizedBox(
            width: context.width(),
            height: context.height(),
            child: Chewie(controller: _chewieController!),
          )
        : SizedBox(
            width: context.width(),
            height: context.height(),
          );
  }
}
```

Expected behaviour i want the channel source to update in the video box when the use click on the channel. But it does not it keep in initai video source but when i navigate away from the screen and return the video source will now be update.

I wanted it to update on the fly.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things what can cause the problem.

1. Your Provider is not correct, but I have to think it is correct, since you didn't show full code of it.
2. You have to give a key to the VideoPlayerBox, you can do something like:

```
...  
SizedBox(
  height: context.height() / 3.8,
  child: VideoPlayerBox(
           channelProvider.getSelectedVideo,  
           key: const ValueKey(channelProvider.getSelectedVideo.channel['link']),
),
)
...
```

If your provider is correct, this should work. Maybe you can take a look here: https://youtu.be/kn0EOS-ZiIc?t=313

Comment: I can share my full provider code if you want please. Am stuck here.

Comment: Passing the key works wow! Thanks bro!

Comment: :) You welcome! Would be cool if i also get a thumbs up :P